# Parsing pandas DateTime where there are different timezones in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to parse a .csv file into a dataframe. The csv has multiple timezones because of daylight savings that happened during the recording of the data (ones at +01:00 others at +02:00). Here's a snippet for understanding:

[image]

After reading in the csv file, I have setup my code as follows:

```
df_vitals.Date_time = pd.to_datetime(df_vitals.Date_time, format ='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
df_vitals.Date_time = df_vitals.Date_time.dt.tz_convert("Europe/Madrid")
```

Where `Date_time` is my column containing the mixed timezones. I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

Note that this works perfectly fine for my csv files with just one time zone (i.e. where no daylight savings happened)

How can I properly parse csv files that have more than one time zone in it?

Comment: your input has multiple UTC offsets (not time zones, to be precise). A pandas Series of the pandas datetime type however can only handle one UTC offset or one specific time zone. That's why pd.to_datetime returns a pd.Series of Python datetime objects here (not pandas datetime) - which does not allow to use the `dt` accessor.

Comment: Great explanation of why it was doing this @MrFuppes - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `format`, set the `utc` param of [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

> `utc` (boolean): Return UTC `DatetimeIndex` if `True` (converting any tz-aware `datetime.datetime` objects as well).

```
df_vitals.Date_time = pd.to_datetime(df_vitals.Date_time, utc=True)
```